# extract data from text formatted in columns

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have multiple lines I would like to extract from text formatted in columns. How do I get the entire column?

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
textA   textB   textC
textAA  textBB  textCC
```

I am familiar with sed and awk tools, but not sure how to use them if for this example I wanted to show all data in column2

Comment: Welcome, the data and the header?

Comment: so I run a command that ouput the ethernet interfaces of a device...column1 would be the eth port, column2 would be MAC addesses. I want to parse the MAC addresses from  all the other data that is displayed in this command (5 total columns) but all I care about in this case is collecting the MAC add.

Comment: It would be better if you [edit] the question presenting the actual use case and sample data, and what process you want to do with it. It would seem an [X Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Please show actual data, and ideally also the command that generated it.

Comment: Since you're familiar with awk, it's not clear why this problem would have you stumped as it's the most basic awk operation   there is. Maybe there's more to it than you've stated and shown in your question? Please [edit] your question to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is awk

```bsh
awk '{print $2}' filename
```

For more info about awk, click the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) tag then click the "Learn more" link.